How to get WooCommerce product category url to display it in HTML meta tag?
Below I am able to display the product permalink when it's a single product page, but I want to do the same for a product category archive pages.
Here is my code:
<meta name="twitter:url" content="<?php
if( is_product_category() ){
   $cat_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);
   echo $category; // category link
} else
the_permalink(); ?>" />

What I get is an empty echo for product category archives.
How to get WooCommerce product category url to display it in HTML meta tag?

For WooCommerce product category (custom taxonomy) use WordPress get_term_link() function like:
<meta name="twitter:url" content="<?php
if( is_product_category() ){
    $term_link = get_term_link(get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat');
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        echo $term_link;
    }
} else {
    the_permalink(); 
} ?>" />

It should work.

Maybe you should write like this:
$cat_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);
**echo $cat_link**; // category link

